# ZFS won't find filesystem when run from cron

Tags: backup, bash, zfs, zfsonlinux

I [wrote a small script](https://gist.github.com/laurentdinclaux/4242d18b7f16cd78b789ad9794d8bbba) to handle my zfs backups. When i run it by hand, it works well:

```
/root/bin/zfs-backup -k 7 -p zfs-auto-snap_daily -r vm/containers tank/backups
```

But running it in cron like so, throws an error "The file system 'vm/containers' doesn't exists."

```
30 0 * * * root /root/bin/zfs-backup -k 7 -p zfs-auto-snap_daily -r vm/containers tank/backups
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It was all about zfs not being found because of the limited PATH in crontabs (/usr/bin:/bin), I added the full path to zfs in my script (/sbin/zfs) and it now works.

Comment: Whenever something works in a regular shell but not through cron, always always always verify your environment. Odds are pretty good that that's where your problem is.